# in MVC musicstore sample app, what if Session overdue, how can the shopping cart items be deleted automatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, shopping-cart

if a user's session overdue, how could be the carts stored in database automatically deleted!

or if there is a better impletemetion of musicstore shoppingcart. http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/

cookie-based is better!

Comment: it's useless , every time a new session begins, a cart item will generated....

Comment: so? they generated, and? Do you experience any **real issue** with them? Or it is just a discomfort sense?

Comment: then probably this question need to be asked to psychologist :-S

Answer (score 0):

One idea: Don't store the cart items in the database, just store them in a session variable?